# Cannot report problem when clicking menu item

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I can't report a problem with visual studio going in help > Send Feedback > Report Problem. I click on the menu item and nothing happens. I ask for help here since there is no other way to get support for VS i could find.

Answer (score 1):

Re-install Visual Studio Code or update to another version of it.

Comment: i will try to do a repair from vs installer, thanks